# Can't register new user vue/express/mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, vue.js

I'm trying to register a new user at my webapp. On my local windows machine with xampp it's working perfectly. But on a vServer it's giving an internal server error.

The request payload is correct. PM2 also is showing the mysql queries and the connection to the database is successful.

It's showing one error to me even tho it's exactly the same database as on my local system, so I don't know if it's really a problem:

```
Connecting to database 'ucb-pvapp' as root@localhost:3306
Ready on port 60702.
query: SELECT * FROM app_users WHERE username='t2@test.de' LIMIT 1
query: INSERT INTO app_users SET `username` = 't2@test.de', `password` = '$2b$10$.tFkbrx.8yXbsdKo4mYn7erzMT/4kSciNRvfpzVms/VhAZfeIoeey'
{ Error: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'is_active' doesn't have a default value
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
    at Promise (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/db.js:21:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.query (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/db.js:17:10)
    at router.post (/var/www/server/pvapp-server/routes/user.js:27:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
  errno: 1364,
  sqlMessage: 'Field \'is_active\' doesn\'t have a default value',
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  index: 0,
```

Maybe there are some other database problems or something with the server being a vServer of my university.
Phpmyadmin is giving me the following errors on the startpage:

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated.

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run this SQL query and check again

```
ALTER TABLE `app_users` CHANGE `is_active` `is_active` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: I changed the default value in phpmyadmin but now it's telling me, other fields don't have a default value. Guess that's not the problem why it's not working.

Comment: Okay, somehow it was the problem. Even tho it's no problem on my local machine. Thanks mate. :)